# Clone whole partitioning scheme to smaller disk

Tags: macos, hard-drive, partition, disk-format

I have the following on my secondary disk. As I am not satisfied with it I would like to clone everything to the other one which is smaller unfortunately.

```
/dev/disk2
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *750.2 GB   disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Clone                   120.5 GB   disk2s2
   3:                  Apple_HFS Data                    578.7 GB   disk2s3
   4:          Apple_CoreStorage                         49.4 GB    disk2s4
   5:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk2s5
/dev/disk3
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Yosemite HD            *48.7 GB    disk3
```

I would like to clone the whole thing except making the disk2s3 (Data) smaller to compensate for the smaller drive.

Can this be done?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend cloning at all, but since you're asking to clone to a smaller disk I would strongly advise you not to do this. Can't you  copy the stuff you really need?

Comment: That is what I have done eventually. But thanks for your reply.